# PHP no guarda las variables

Tags: php, ajax, reactjs, phpmailer

tengo un formulario con react y php y resulta que php sí manda el mail pero sin los datos pasados por el formulario de tal forma que la plantilla me llega vacía, sabran que podrá ser?

Probé con inicializar las variables pero no creo que sirva de mucho y anteriormente probé con PHPMailer pero tuve muchos problemas por eso decidi usar la funcion mail() estandar de php.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Codigo de react

```
 onSubmit: (values) =>{
                const url = "https://programmark.com/enviar.php"
                const data = {
                    fullname:values.fullname,
                    email:values.email,
                    text:values.text
                }
                fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                    headers:{
                        "Content-type": "application/json"
                    }
                }).then(res=> alert("The form has been send!"), console.log(data))
                  .catch(err=> alert("The form could not be send :("))
```

Codigo de PHP

```
<?php 
//CUANDO SUBAS TODO AL HOST CORROBORÁ LAS DIRECCIONES URL DE LOS ARCHIVOS(PAGE.JSX[AJAX] Y DEMAS)
echo "mensaje de prueba";

        $fullname = "";
        $mail = "";
        $text = "";
        
        $fullname=htmlspecialchars($_POST['fullname'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $mail = $_POST['email'];
        $text = $_POST['text'];
        if(($fullname!==''||$fullname!==null)&&($mail!==''||$mail!==null)){
    
        //Destinatary
          $to= 'xxx';
          $title='Mail sent from Programmark.com';
          $message=
            "<html>
                <head>
                    <title>$title</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h4>Fullname: $fullname</h4>
                    <h4>Mail: $mail</h4>
                    <p>Message: $text</p>
                </body>
            </html>";
            $header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
            mail($to,$title,$message,$header);
        }
```

Comment: Se que no ayudó con lo que preguntas, pero te doy un par de consejos: 1) Cuidado con las palabras mal sonantes en tus textos de relleno, te pueden traer más de un dolor de cabeza innecesario. 2) Si existen herramientas como PHPMailer es mejor usarlo, y si, se que puede ser una paliza aprender a usarlo, pero es mucho mejor que intentar crear nuestras propias librerías (Excepto para aprender). 3)Quizá no lo sabes, pero existen instaladores de librerías como simphony que ayudan a instalar estas(También es una pesadilla instalarlo, pero una vez aprendas no tendrás más problemas y sabrás más)

Comment: Si haces un ```var_dump($_POST]';``` al principio, que te imprime en pantalla? Primer comprobaría que estas obteniendo los datos correctamente.